# VBA: wdDialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs) .name will only give me a default path or default filename not both

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to use the following code to open a word Save As dialog from an excel module. This is the code:

```
With appWrd.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\" & "AFileName.docx"
    .Format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
    .Show
End With
```

This gives me a dialog window with "AFileName" in the name field, but the path shown is the word templates folder. I can get the correct path by just including the folder path and excluding the file name but of course this leaves the name field blank:

```
With appWrd.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\"
    .Format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
    .Show
End With
```

I can't seem to get both the path name and the file name. I am using Office 2016. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does changing the current directory to `"C:\Users\Me\Documents\"` (i.e. `ChDir "C:\Users\Me\Documents"`) before using the `.Name = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\AFileName.docx"` version work?

Comment: Tested in MS Office 2013. Your code works fine for me till the time the path exists. Are you sure you have "Me" in the path `"C:\Users\Me\Documents\"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using the ChDir command before the code and as part of of the with block without any success. The latest I have found is that it works if "C:\Users\Me\Documents\AFileName.docx" already exists.  If "AFileName.docx" is replaced with any document that already exists in the folder the code will work. But I want to create a new file based on a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and probably resolved by now, but I've had this issue myself in Word-based projects. In my experience, Word (and apparently Excel, too) doesn't like dealing with 2 variables in paths. To get around this, create your path as a string composed of the two variables:

```
dim strFullPath as string
dim strRootPath as string
dim strFileName as string

strRootPath = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\"
strFileName = "AFileName.docx"
strFullPath = strRootPath & strFileName

With appWrd.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = strFullPath
    .Format = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
    .Show
End With
```

I cannot explain why VBA won't accept two variables for .name, but this is how I've handled it in my projects. You might run into an issue if the path doesn't actually exist (there are ways to check for that), but from your comments, it seems you know the path is valid so I'm assuming that here. Probably too late for OP, but maybe it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

When using the wdDialogFileSaveAs, the folder part of the path, that you are setting as part of the .Name property, must exist in order for it to open the dialog to that path.

The name of the file name isn't really relevant to this issue, except to display name you are suggesting they save the file as.  If the folder path itself doesn't exist, the dialog opens to the default document location for MS - most likely the "Documents Library" on the user machine.

The solution is one that requires you to check that the path first exists, and if it doesn't, choose: 
1) create the folder path for the user since it's the "expected" location and should exist (NOTE: You'll need to capture if the folder was successfully created and/or exists after you attempt creation because the create operation could fail for a number of reasons), then open the wdDialogFileSaveAs dialog.
2) prompt the user with a "select folder" type of dialog (Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)), then the wdDialogFileSaveAs (or one operation to choose/create a folder, and then you save as the expected file name to the chosen location). 
3) let the wdDialogFileSaveAs fail-over to the default folder path MS.
4) tell the user "Sorry - can't do that because the folder doesn't exist".

HTH